# GAM Model: How can I fit GAM Model for daily count variable in the time-series dataset?

Tags: time-series, nonparametric, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

I am trying to apply GAM Model on one Health Claims Dataset (from 2007 to 2018), trying to find the association between daily hospital admissions of heart diseases) and temperature.

> **all:** daily number of hospital admissions, which assumed to follow quasi-Poisson distribution
>
> **tmk_mw:** temperature
>
> **ndate:** date, for example 01-01-2017
>
> **doy:** day of the month
>
> **week:** a dummy variable for day of the week
>
> **vor_nach_2012:** categorical variable;
> 0: before 2012
> 1:after 2012
> (because the daily number of hospital admission have a clear increase after year 2012,from 2012 to 2018 the daily number is obviously higher)

```r
mod2 <-  gam(all ~ s(tmk_mw) + s(ndate) +  te(doy, ndate, 
    bs = c("cc", "tp"), k=c(20,30)) +  s(nyear) + s(nmonth) + 
       week + vor_nach_2012,  data=mydata,method = "REML",
       family = quasipoisson)

summary(mod2)
```

[image]

It seems that the variable temperature is not significant. How should I revise the model?

[image]

```
plot(mod2,all.terms = TRUE,residuals = TRUE, pages =1)
```

[image]

Then I plotted the fitted value as well

```
pdata <- mutate(mydata, myfitted = predict(mod2))

ggplot(pdata, aes(x = ndate,y = all)) + 
   geom_point() + geom_line(aes(y = exp(myfitted)), 
   col = 'red')
```

[image]

The purpose here is to quantify the exposure-response relationship between temperature and daily hospital admissions.

The graphic shows the relationship between Relative Risk and temperature. How can we create a graphic like this after we fit our GAM model with function from mgcv or other package?
[image]

Comment: I would also help to see how you fitted your GAM; what you are showing likely isn't possible with a GAM (unless you did something very unusual) so it could just be an issue with the visualization. It is impossible to help you with what information you have given us in this question.

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson I used the function exp() on my fitted value. Because i assumed a quasi-Poisson distribution, and y = ln(µ) . i revised my question and added more imformation

Comment: Thomas, many users might reflexively vote to close this post, because it asks how to do something in `R` (apparently a software-only question), I think there nevertheless is an underlying statistical question: namely, what does that last plot (of relative risk vs. a single explanatory variable) represent and how is such a plot created generally, regardless of the software environment.  Consider including this clarification in your post.

Comment: thanks for the comment and advice. @whuber. i revised the question. acutally i am trying to figure out how to generate that Relative Risk graphic with mgcv Package.

Comment: The obvious problem is that you’re plotting the predicted values for all the observed data and not a smooth grid over the covariate of interest. But I think a more general problem is that you aren’t decomposing the time information into different components of temporal variation. I’m traveling for most of today but I’ll take a closer look later if no one has answered by the

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks for pointing out the problems. Still trying to understand the decompose by timeseries data. Any advices for statistic dummies like me will be much appreciated.